# C# Winforms System.Threading.Timer

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, timer

I am having trouble with this code being used in multiple window forms:

```
  private void Window_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {   
     new System.Threading.Timer((state) => 
     { 
         BeginInvoke((Action)delegate() 
         {
             if (!CurrentTimeDate.IsHandleCreated) return;
             CurrentTimeDate.Text = "    " +    DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss") + "  " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(); 
         }); 

     }, null, 0, 1000);
  }
```

When I show the form at first click, it works well, and then I press close button of the window form. I click again the button to show the form again then it shows this error:

> InvalidOperationException: Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a
>   control until the window handle has been created

Edit: I thought it is solved but the code still shows error

Comment: There is no point whatsoever in using a System.Timers.Timer and then use BeginInvoke() in the Elapsed event handler.  Use a regular Winforms timer for the *exact* same outcome, minus the crash.  Drop it from the toolbox onto the form, the timer will be automatically disposed when the user closes the form, thus automatically stopping it as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's the timer which continue to run, after you're form has been closed. 
Try save the instance of the timer, and in the Form_Closing event call `timer.Dispose()`

Comment: Thanks it worked but the application does not close completely. How do I fix it?

Comment: Sounds like there still some threads running in the background... The `Dispose` methods closes the timer's thread, but there might me other threads.